# CFReadStream - start in the background

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, core-foundation

there's an audio application which streams files via network, everything works fine but one thing. To play the next track automatically in the background the CFReadStream is initialized (i can see it in the log) after the AudioQueueStop is called, but the callback is never called (edit: actually is called once) until the app enters foreground. Piece of code for stream init:

```
    //also tried main runloop just for test, no luck 
CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(stream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
```

The wired thing is that the app is functional after the queue is stopped, the stream is being initialized but the callback is properly called only if the stream was initialized in the foreground mode. Here is a piece of code for callback:

```
    CFReadStreamSetClient(stream,
                      kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred | kCFStreamEventEndEncountered,
                      MyReadStreamCallBack,
                      &context);
```

On the other hand, the callback is called when the application is in the background and the next track is triggered not automatically but with the app-delegate (with the same function).

I don't completely understand the difference between that three cases, please help.

Edit.

```
OSStatus status = AudioFileStreamOpen(self, MyAudioListener ...
```

MyAudioListener callback is being called while MyReadStreamCallBack is called **just once**.

Edit 2

the ReadStream callback is most often not being called even once, one time is the maximum of what i was able to see.

On the other hand, and that drives me to misunderstanding of what's happening, after **the previous AudioQueue is stopped** and the next track is a **local file**, then **another AudioQueue is opened**, it reads the file with AudioFileReadPackets and i don't have to awake the application from background to start the next track playback as **it plays** itself in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Audio Queue will continue run in the background, given the approprate background modes.  But once stopped, it seems that an Audio Queue will not start running in the background.  The one callback is probably just to prime the buffer so the the queue can start immediately after being brought to the foreground.

The only solution I've found is to not stop the previous Audio Queue when in the background, but to somehow feed new audio data to the old Audio Queue left running, without underflowing any callbacks in between.

Comment: That is very helpful, any comments of why the AudioQueue is starting and working in the background though if the next track is stored locally and another streamer is used (it doesn't waits for the network callback but uses recursed AudioFileReadPackets instead) ?

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps if the audio data for the next track is available immediately and before the AQ really completely stops (as opposed to being asked to stop), it doesn't really stop.

Comment: great help indeed, i was ended with adding a background task for the network streamer to wait until the callback receives enough data to fill one of the buffers and starts the AudioQueue (it has not really been started - AudioQueueStart hasn't been called as there were no data to play). A code scheme will follow for everyone interested.

Answer (score 0):

The current solution is to add a background job to wait until there's a data to start a new queue with (starting queue w/o data gives -50 error and i believe hangs a hw decoder).

Let's say in the streamer Play function there's openNetworkStream function with something like this:

```
// ...whatever we need to be happy 


// start the background job
UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
BOOL isBackgroundSupported = NO;
if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
    isBackgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;

if(isBackgroundSupported && waitForQueueToStartBackgroundTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
    waitForQueueToStartbackgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:waitForQueueToStartBackgroundTask];
        waitForQueueToStartBackgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
}

// Open the stream
if (!CFReadStreamOpen(stream)) {
```

You should have haven an AudioQueueStart call somewhere, for me it was StreamEnqueueBuffer function used to hanlde the downloaded pieces of data as the buffers are ready to be played or the end of the file is reached (AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer), this function is also an initial-starter of the AudioQueue as we need the buffers to be filled to start it. My solution was to end the initialized a started background job here as the queue is started:

```
OSStatus StreamEnqueueBuffer(AudioNetworkStreamer* aStreamer)

// wahtever you need to be happy with a filled buffer

if (!aStreamer->didStart) {     // start the queue if it has not been started already
    aStreamer->isBuffering = NO;
    [aStreamer startQueue];

    UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    BOOL isBackgroundSupported = NO;
    if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
        isBackgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;

    if(isBackgroundSupported && aStreamer->waitForQueueToStartBackgroundTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:aStreamer->waitForQueueToStartBackgroundTask];
        aStreamer->waitForQueueToStartBackgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
}

    // nandle mutexes, flags ...
```